# Ubuntu 22.04: gnome-terminal keeps crashing during high/enduring disk activity

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, crash

I'm using vanilla Ubuntu 22.04, GNOME.
`gnome-terminal` keeps crashing. It seems to be associated with any high-bandwidth, disk-intensive activity. I'm creating a tar file of considerable size (4GB) and `gnome-terminal` crashes. I'm downloading a large(-ish) file via the web browser - `gnome-terminal` crashes. I'm doing a multi-gigabyte transfer over the network, `gnome-terminal` crashes. When it crashes, I get nothing more than `[server exited unexpectedly]` and a dead window. (All tabs/windows that were open are dead.)  I can find nothing unusual reported in `/var/log/syslog`

Anyone have any ideas?